# View events not firing - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am building a view at the moment, and when I click on a `.organisation` link I want to fire my edit event, however on clicking this element, nothing is fired, and I cannot understand why.

Here is the code that builds my view,

```
App.Views.groupsView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '.app',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-groups-base').html() ),

events: {

},

initialize: function(options) {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template() );

    var orgTab = new App.Views.OrganisationsTab({
        collection : new App.Collections.Organisations
    });

},
```

});

```
App.Views.OrganisationsTab = Backbone.View.extend({

el : '#organisations',

initialize: function() {
    App.Collections.OrganisationCollection = this.collection;
    this.collection.fetch();

    this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
},

render: function() {
    this.addAll();
    return this;
},

addAll: function() {
    App.Collections.OrganisationCollection.each(this.addOne, this);
},

addOne: function(organisation) {

    var view = new App.Views.OrganisationView({
        model : organisation
    });

    this.$el.append( view.render().el );
}
```

});

```
App.Views.OrganisationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'a',
    className:'group group--panel col-sm-3 organisation',

    template : _.template( $('#tpl-single-group').html() ),

    events: {
        "click body" : "edit",
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'destory', this.remove);
    },

    render: function() {

        this.$el.html( this.template({
            group: this.model.toJSON()
        }));

        return this;
    },

    edit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.model);
    }

});
```

Why would I not be able to click on the organisation a that is created in the final view, and trigger my edit function?

Comment: apparently an `a` needs to have a href before it can have click event.

Comment: If trust what is written in the `events` tag `a` must contain a `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach a click event listener to a child element of a view's el

```
events: {
    "click .organisation" : "edit",
},
```

If you want to attach it to the el

```
events: {
        "click" : "edit",
 },
```